# when I added the firebase_dynamic_links plugin I got This error in flutter > File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@fa121b8'

Tags: flutter

the full error message
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@1e2d5e4f' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: try running `flutter clean` in the terminal and `flutter pub get` too then build your project again.

Comment: its not working